# New-MoveRequest with primary only and archive database issue

Tags: exchange, migration

I am in a wierd situation due to mistake in migration of an exchange 2007 user mailbox to exchange 2010.

I have a user with existing archive database that I moved with primary only option without disabling archive.

Now I am not able to migrate archive mailbox for the same user, because when I try it it says guid mismatch between source and destination archive

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

While migrating from the Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010 you have to follow certain steps which are:

1) Administrative Rights
2) Active Directory Permission for the new users creation (if you are creating) while migrating the data from existing exchange to new exchange.
3) While you are migrating you should also need to take care of things like Special Identification of each users when you are moving from the existing Exchange to the new Exchange
4) Even after migration (Whether it will be using a tool or manually), you need to create every user profile manually and it will ask for the outlook version. 
5) You also have to take use of the cmdlet command to move the data. 
6) During the move you also need to take care of the SMTP for moving  purpose.
7) Proper two way routing connection.

Thanks

For more you can follow [link](http://www.msexchangegeek.com/2010/01/30/rapid-transition-guide-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010/)